# How to create unique id in firebase in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I am using first time using firebase database. I don't know how to generate unique id firebase.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `push().getKey()` to get the unique key

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
String key = database.getReference("quiz").push().getKey();
```

Comment: Will key create a totaly random id?

Comment: Yes. It is a random id.

Answer (score 1):

As I see in your database, you have already used the `push()` method to generate a unique key for your quiz object. If you want, you can use for your `quizid` property the same key. So your database will look like this:

```
Firebase-root
   |
   --- quiz
        |
        --- -LlC8 ... XwOe
              |
              --- quizid: "-LlC8 ... XwOe"
              |
              --- //Other details
```

To actually get the key, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference quizRef = rootRef.child("quiz");
String key = quizRef.push().getKey();
```

Having this `key`, you can use it to set the `quizid` when adding quiz objects to the database.

If don't want to use the pushed id, there is also another approach which isthe [UUID](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) which can help you generate unique keys for your `quizid` property.

Comment: Have you tried my solution above, does it work?